# Swift Measurement notation for UnitType

Tags: swift, foundation, measurement

new to swift, learning from a book. They use following in an example :

```
var stepsTaken : Measurement<UnitLength>
```

so this says that stepsTaken is a variable of Type `Measurement<UnitLength>`

I looked up Measurement in Apple developer docs and also UnitType. What I don't understand (and don't find an explanation for) is why the <> ? I get it that you have to give a UnitType to a Measurement but why put that in between < and > ? Is this a special Swift notation or so? I looked up Structs in Swift but don't see such notation there...

I also looked at the video of session 238 of WWDC 2016 where they talk about Measurements. They use the same notation but no explanation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/774/generics/5623/the-basics-of-generics#t=201701271146131807228

Comment: Its "notation", not "notification".

Comment: It's notation for generics. You can read about it in the [Swift Book](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html)

Answer (score 0):

When we create a Measurement, we give it a value and a unit. That unit becomes a generic constraint on the measurement.

For example, Triathlon 
• a 25km bike ride
• a 3 nautical mile swim
• a half marathon run

Let's see how we can create some measurements representing these lengths

```
let cycleRide = Measurement(value: 25, unit: UnitLength.kilometers) 
let swim = Measurement(value: 3, unit: UnitLength.nauticalMiles) 
let marathon = Measurement(value: 26, unit: UnitLength.miles) + Measurement(value: 385, unit: UnitLength.yards)
```

The unit for the marathon is **m**, which is the base unit for `UnitLength`. That's because we added two distances of different `UnitLength` instances together for it.

```
marathon.unit.symbol
swim.unit.symbol
cycleRide.unit.symbol
```

**Find a half-marathon:**

```
let run = marathon / 2
```

**Total event distance:**

```
let triathlon = cycleRide + swim + run
```